# make array object in for loop with horizontal view

Tags: php, arrays

```
 <?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=London');
    $information = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_information");
    $current = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions");
    $forecast_list = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_conditions");
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Weather API</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?php print $information[0]->city['data']; ?></h1>
        <h2>Today's weather</h2>
        <div class="weather">       
            <img src="<?php echo  'http://www.google.com' . $current[0]->icon['data']?>" alt="weather"?>
            <span class="condition">
            <?php echo round(conver_f_c($current[0]->temp_f['data'])); ?>&deg; C,
            <?php echo $current[0]->condition['data'] ?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <h2>Forecast</h2>
        <?php foreach ($forecast_list as $forecast) : ?>
        <div class="weather">
            <img src="<?php echo 'http://www.google.com' . $forecast->icon['data']?>" alt="weather"?>
            <div><?php echo $forecast->day_of_week['data']; ?></div>
            <span class="condition">
                <?php echo round(conver_f_c($forecast->low['data'])); ?>&deg; C - <?php echo round(conver_f_c($forecast->high['data'])); ?>&deg; C,
                <?php echo $forecast->condition['data'] ?>
            </span>
        </div>  
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
function conver_f_c($F){

    return  $C = ($F − 32) * 5/9;
}
```

I want Out somthing like this manner of the horizontal ,

Even i tried UL LI WITH display inline but it goes failed,

Tell me some good suggestion for my probme,

I want exactly like horizontal, expecting exactly like screen shot ,

Tell me How to render using php
Thanks

[alt text http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/7518/weatherhori.jpg](http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/7518/weatherhori.jpg)

Above snippet present display out verticly , i want o change that verticle to horizonatal ,
somthing like this screen shot

Comment: Please format your code properly. No one can read this. Code has to be indented by four spaces. And you are expecting a lot... Btw. why do you use a list for what is not a list. A table would be indeed more appropriate. And post your PHP code... but it is most likely a CSS issues and has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Yes folks, it's not SO's editor removing the whitespace - he pasted the array contents in like that.

Comment: You paste what looks like a XML tree and ask advice about layout. I've assumed you were asking an HTML question (despite the tags) but if that's not the case you should clarify what part of the process is giving you problems.

Comment: the snippet is weather report on, i want the our should somthing like screen shot which pasted above

Comment: @Bharanikumar: Yes, we all understand what you want to accomplish. What's not clear is what you expect from us. Do you need help with SimpleXML? Do you need help with Google API? Do you need help with CSS? Do you want someone to write the complete code for you and install it in your client's server?

Comment: i know how to fetch array and display it, but i dont know to fetch and display in the verticl manner that is the stuck up

Comment: I think you need to post the output screenshot you mentioned in your question to make the problem clear for others.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>...</table>
```

### Update

From your latest comment so far:

> i know how to fetch array and display
>   it, but i dont know to fetch and
>   display in the verticl manner that is
>   the stuck up

I feel this is going to be a stupid answer but it appears to be what you don't understand...

The web is based in a markup language called HTML. This language has tags (delimited by angle-brackets) that allow you to define the structure of a document. On top of this, you have another language called CSS. This other lang allow you to define how HTML is going to be displayed on screen.

You may argue that you already have a web page and you've written it with the PHP language instead of the two other langs I've mentioned. That's not enterely true: you code in PHP, sure, but you use PHP to *generate* HTML. And it's HTML what finally reaches the browser (Firefox, Explorer...). PHP is executed in the web server, not in the browser. The browser can only see whatever HTML you've generated.

To sum up: you have to forget about PHP, Google and the whole weather thingy. You first need to write a static HTML document and style it with CSS. Once you've done with it, you can finally replace the parts of the information that are dynamic with values taken from your PHP variables.

And since you seem to need a table to display tabular data, the appropriate HTML tag is `<table>`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Web</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="/path/to/pics/cloudy.png" width="25" height="25" alt="Cloudy"></td>
        <td><img src="/path/to/pics/sunny.png" width="25" height="25" alt="Sunny"></td>
        <td><img src="/path/to/pics/rainy.png" width="25" height="25" alt="Rainy"></td>
        <td><img src="/path/to/pics/cloudy.png" width="25" height="25" alt="Cloudy"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>26ºC</td>
        <td>26ºC</td>
        <td>22ºC</td>
        <td>25ºC</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

I suggest you find some tutorials about basic HTML and CSS. They'll be of invaluable help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's done by Google :

http://jsfiddle.net/bW8NA/1

Comment: First please understnad . what  am asking , if my question is not an understandable manner , plz excuse me ,
i know html,css layout design , the thing is in the weather please look , To display three days weather , i used foreach , My problem is ,How to use the table tr td  inside the foreach , becoz if i create table in side foreach , every time table will create , and also that wont make in horozonatl view, it simple dislay verticle view only,,,

Comment: padding: 5px 5px 0pt; float: left; problem fixed